# Usage of "Rather"

Tags: grammar, word-usage, adverbs

I'm a bit of crossroads which one is to use. Here's an example:
-You're behaving rather **strange**; or
-You're behaving rather **strangely**;
I'm not sure which one is correct or maybe these two are both correct. Nonetheless, here's another example:
-He was looking rather **condescending** at me; or
-He was looking rather **condescendingly** at me;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're modifying a verb, you use an adverb, such as "strangely" or "condescendingly".

If you're modifying a noun, you use an adjective, such as "strange" or "condescending".

The addition of "rather" doesn't change these rules. It's an adverb that can modify another adjective or adverb.

Since "looking" and "behaving" are verbs, you should use the adverb after "rather".

Answer (score 2):

The correct sentence: He was looking at me rather condescendingly

It’s also correct: He was looking rather condescending. But it describes how he was looking.

Comment: I agree, though it's worth noting that the verb "looking" has two different meanings in those examples. In your first, "looking" means something similar to "gazing, watching". In your second, "He was looking" means something like "To me, he seemed...". And when "look" is used in that sense, the progressive aspect is not as idiomatic as the plain aspect. "He looked..." is more idiomatic.